# Changing a String array for a JComboBox depending on another value in another ComboBox

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I'm trying to create a Combobox, where, when a value is changed in the first Combobox, in this case which is "FlightNumber", to change the String array in another Combobox in the same window, which is "Baggage" depending on which value is selected in the FlightNumber Combobox.

Every time I try to do this, the program hangs after selecting a Flight number from the drop down menu.

```
 private void jComboBox_flightNumberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt((String)jComboBox_flightNumber.getSelectedItem());
    boolean found = false;
    int baggageSize = 0;
    int counter;
    System.out.println(this.flightList.size());
    System.out.println(number);
    for(counter = 0; counter < this.flightList.size() || !found; counter++){
        Flight flight = this.flightList.get(counter);
        if(flight.getFlightID() == number) { 
            found = true;
            baggageSize = flight.getBaggage();
            System.out.println(baggageSize);
        }else{
        found = false;
        }
    }
    
     String [] baggageLength = new String[baggageSize];
    for(int x = 0;counter < baggageLength.length; x++) { 
        baggageLength[counter] = Integer.toString((x+1));

    }
    
    this.baggageSize = baggageLength;
    
    jComboBox_baggage.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(this.baggageSize));
    jComboBox_baggage.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jComboBox_baggageActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. No need to add action listener again and again.  remove `jComboBox_baggage.addActionListener` (do it once when `jComboBox_baggage` is constructed). For more help post [mcve]

Comment: See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362898/how-to-change-combobox-options-depending-on-the-selected-item-of-a-different-com for a simple example